# Changing background, color and text using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to change background color, text color, and text using jquery, however background color and text color is changing but text(string) not,
Im using this code:

```
$('#page_'+(vector.length)).css("background", "orange");
$('#page_'+(vector.length)).css("color", "black");
$('#page_'+(vector.length)).css("text", "string");
```

I think the third line is writted bad, thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `.css()` to alter an element's text?

Comment: In addition to Felix's correct answer, for performance reasons you may want to cache the jQuery object to a variable to avoid having to repeatedly query the DOM - "var element = $('#page_'+(vector.length)); element.css({ "background": "orange", "color": "black" }); element.text("string");" - see http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties for details on setting multiple styles simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** instead of `css()` to change text inside your element:

```
$('#page_'+(vector.length)).text("string");
```